# View not updating synchronously

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Before I go any further, here is my ViewPart class:

```
public class Exp extends ViewPart {

public static final String ID = "edu.bitsgoa.views.Exp"; //$NON-NLS-1$
public static Text text;

public Exp() {
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    sc.setContent(composite);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    Font newFont=new Font(text.getDisplay(),new FontData("Monospace",10,SWT.NATIVE));
    text.setFont(newFont);

    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).hint(400, 400).applyTo(text);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    createActions();
    initializeToolBar();
    initializeMenu();
}


private void createActions() {
    // Create the actions
}
private void initializeToolBar() {
    IToolBarManager toolbarManager = getViewSite().getActionBars()
            .getToolBarManager();
}
private void initializeMenu() {
    IMenuManager menuManager = getViewSite().getActionBars()
            .getMenuManager();
}
public void setFocus() {
    // Set the focus
}

}
```

I have create this class to act as a console, so that I can print data on it from my custom plugin. This is how I display data on it (this may be a very naive approach, but works to some extent):

```
public static void display(final String message){
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Exp.text.append(message);
            Exp.text.append("\n");
        }
    });
}
```

This method is in some different class. Whenever I have to print something on the console, I called this method as:

```
Preparation.display("Calculating parameters...);
calculateParameters();
Preparation.display("Done");
```

Now, the problem is that in the above three lines, the data is not printed on the console as:

```
Calculating parameters...
(wait for some time, calculate parameters)
Done
```

Instead, the parameters are calculated first, and then everything is printed at once, as:

```
(wait for some time, calculate parameters) 
Calculating parameters...
Done
```

I want it to be done synchronously, as I call the display method. I am very new to SWT and Java graphics in general. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not showing the code that outputs "(wait for some time...". Is it in a different thread? Does it use the same `Preparation.display()` method? Have you noticed that you're calling `asyncExec()` instead of `syncExec()`?

Comment: The code is nothing special. It just runs an executable, and prints the result to an external .txt file. It does not run in a different thread, I just call a method I have tried syncExec(), but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Are you running the `Preparation.display` code in a separate thread? If you are running in the UI thread `asyncExec` is useless and will just delay things. To get what you want you must run the calculation code in a separate thread.

Comment: @greg-449 The code is nothing special. It just runs an executable, and prints the result to an external .txt file. It does not run in a different thread, I just call a method I have tried syncExec(), but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: A long running task in the UI thread will lock up the UI and nothing will update until it finishes. You must use a background thread.

Comment: Take at look at [Eclipse Jobs and Background Processing](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html)

Comment: Going through it, sir. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @greg-449 I tried running the calculation part in a separate thread. Still, the results are sames. Even if the UI locks-up due to a heavy task going-on, the line "Calculating Parameters..." should be displayed first, and then the UI should freeze, shouldn't it? With me, it is printed only when the "calculateParameters() method returns.

Comment: If you do it correctly the UI will not freeze. Things you do in the UI thread are not necessarily shown instantly - they wait for the next 'paint' event which will not happen if the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: @greg-449 Can you add your comment as an answer to this question so that I can accept it? I implemented a Runnable class into which I put all the calculation code. Running it on a separate thread solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long running task in the UI thread will lock up the UI and nothing will update until it finishes. You must use a background thread.

Since you are blocking the SWT `readAndDispatch` loop even operations you have done before to long running code starts may not happen until the code ends since they rely on the dispatch loop.

You can just use a normal `Thread` for the background code or you can use an Eclipse `Job`. Jobs allow you to update a 'progress monitor' which reports the work's progress.

In the background thread you can use the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods of `Display` to run code in the UI thread.

For more details see [Eclipse Jobs and Background Processing](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html)